# Out of memory exception in org.apache.spark.memory.MemoryConsumer.allocatePage

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have a python spark job. It is operating on a very small dataset ( less than 8kb). However, when it runs it fails with the following error::

> 2017-02-10 10:06:58,402 ERROR [stdout writer for python] util.Utils
>   (Logging.scala:logError(95)) - Uncaught exception in thread stdout
>   writer for python java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to acquire 172
>   bytes of memory, got 0    at
>   org.apache.spark.memory.MemoryConsumer.allocatePage(MemoryConsumer.java:120)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter.acquireNewPageIfNecessary(UnsafeExternalSorter.java:321)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter.insertRecord(UnsafeExternalSorter.java:336)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.insertRow(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.sort(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Sort$$anonfun$1.apply(Sort.scala:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Sort$$anonfun$1.apply(Sort.scala:64)

Any idea what is going on? I googled for it, but did not find anything that would help me. I did see a lot of posts about this being related to a spark memory leak but they seem to have been fixed in spark ( I have spark 1.6).

Any help or pointers appreciated.

Comment: did you find the solution by any chance? I'm having this in 2.1.1

Comment: I increased the memory allocation to the spark job, and that seemed to make it go away.